# Trouble with get_next_post() get_previous_post() returning null

Tags: query-posts

I'm using wp as an engine to put blog features in an existing site. I have a place in the blog page where I load `wp-load.php`. I want to get the next and previous posts, but when I load a post from from wpdb, both `get_next_post()` and `get_previous_post()` both return `NULL`. What do I need to do to get those functions to return the proper values?

**Edit** Here's the code:

```
if ( isset($_GET['article_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['article_id']) ) {

    $id = $_GET['article_id'];
    $objPost = get_post($id);

    new dBug(get_next_post());
    new dBug(get_previous_post());
```

}

`dBug` is a pretty-printing class. Currently it gives two `NULL`s. I tried this:

```
if ( isset($_GET['article_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['article_id']) ) {

    $id = $_GET['article_id'];
    $objPost = get_post($id);
    setup_postdata($objPost);
    new dBug(get_next_post());
    new dBug(get_previous_post());
```

}
but no luck. Still `NULL`.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Yeah! I don't know why I didn't do it before.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `setup_postdata($post)`.

**get_next_post()** and **get_previous_post()** depend on calls to a number of properties in the global $post variable which is populated by calling `setup_postdata($post)` or `the_post()`. If $post is empty it returns null.

Comment: Another thing: the $post variable has to be named $post in order to work. Instead of `$objPost = get_post($id);` do `$post = get_post($id);`. (You may want to back up the contents of $post first, so you can restore them afterward.)